# NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION error while running the code

Tags: android

I am trying to run a simple code that i saw almost everywhere for uploading a text file from android device on an FTP server. The code is:

```
package com.example.testtrials;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jibble.simpleftp.SimpleFTP;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView text;

    public class FTPFileUpload extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                SimpleFTP ftp = new SimpleFTP();
                // Connect to an FTP server on port 21.
                ftp.connect(params[0], 21, params[1], params[2]);
                // Set binary mode.
                ftp.bin();
                // Change to a new working directory on the FTP server.
                ftp.cwd(params[3]);
                // You can also upload from an InputStream, e.g.
                ftp.stor(new FileInputStream(new File(params[4])), params[5]);
                // Quit from the FTP server.
                ftp.disconnect();
                text.setText("Upload Successful");
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                // Jibble.
            }
            return null;
    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(text);

FTPFileUpload task = new FTPFileUpload();
task.execute(//someArgumets);
    }
}
```

My LogCat displays the following error when i

```
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testtrials/com.example.testtrials.TestActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146)
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3669)
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3541)
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3517)
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:337)
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:327)
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1944)
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:221)
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:105)
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:82)
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at com.example.testtrials.TestActivity.onCreate(TestActivity.java:45)
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188)
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2085)
07-10 13:38:18.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     ... 11 more
```

before i was having `ClassNotFoundException` which seems to be fixed now. Before that it was not detecting the `simpleFTP` library i imported. I had to install new IDE, packages and all. Pretty much stuck now. Can anyone help me fix this? Or help me find a complete FTP upload code that might actually work?

Comment: I want to fix the error on logcat.

Comment: Refer my updated answer. Your oncreate method's setcontent view is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement  `onCreate(...)` of `Activity` and set your layout and then called your `AsynTask` call from `onCreate(......)`

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout); 

    new FTPFileUpload().execute();
}
```

and also you need to Reference your `TextView` in your `onCreate(....)` method like

```
text=findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Comment: I believe @user3770134 will also need to associate the TextView with the actual layout component. E.g. ´text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourIdHere);´ before setting the text

Comment: umm... i have done that. Didin't mention it here only to avoid giving away my password...

Comment: I have removed `text.setText()` and still the error remains the same.

Comment: `text = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.layout)` solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: `07-10 14:03:49.270: E/dalvikvm(6493): Could not find class 'org.jibble.simpleftp.SimpleFTP', referenced from method com.example.testtrials.TestActivity$FTPFileUpload.doInBackground` is the next error and i can't remove it...

Comment: thanks! but now am back to where i started from... just can't resolve this "Could not find class" >.<

Answer (score 0):

`text.setText` is causing the error

1. You cannot use a UI component in the `doInBackground` Method. You will have to use it in the `onPostExecute()` Method.
2. Also text is not initialized.
3. You need to have an OnCreate method in your activity. Where is it? That is where you will have to inflate your xml.

You need to use your code as follows

```
     public class TestActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
     {

           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           //setContentView(text);  ----> WRONG
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);   // ---> Your layout xml name. For example if xml name is activity_login.xml

           FTPFileUpload task = new FTPFileUpload();
           task.execute(//someArgumets);
    }

     TextView text;
     public class FTPFileUpload extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
     -----Your existing code here-----------

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) 
    {
          text=findView(R.id.textView);
          text.setText("Upload Successful");
    }
    }
```

Comment: i have removed `text.setText()`. i am still getting the same error.

Comment: @user3770134: Check my edit #3 about oncreate method